# finicky jquery listener doesnt trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('nobr:contains("Tool or Material?")').closest('tr').show();
    $('nobr:contains("Description")').closest('tr').hide();
    $('nobr:contains("Due Date")').closest('tr').show();
    $('nobr:contains("Notifications")').closest('tr').hide();
    $('nobr:contains("Still required?")').closest('tr').hide();

    $("select[title='Tool or Material?']").change(function() {
        if ($("select[title='Tool or Material?']").val() == "Material") {
            $('nobr:contains("Tool or Material?")').closest('tr').show();
            $('nobr:contains("Description")').closest('tr').hide();
            $('nobr:contains("Due Date")').closest('tr').show();
            $('nobr:contains("Still required?")').closest('tr').hide();
        } else {
            $('nobr:contains("Tool or Material?")').closest('tr').show();
            $('nobr:contains("Description")').closest('tr').show();
            $('nobr:contains("Due Date")').closest('tr').show();
            $('nobr:contains("Still required?")').closest('tr').hide();
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

I'm using jquery to customize a sharepoint list, I've had this code work before where the answer of a title determines what can be ignored and hidden using code but it's super finicky. I can show and hide all parameters but the listener & if else conditions dont trigger.

Comment: `console.log($("select[title='Tool or Material?']").length);` Are you sure the element is there?

Comment: @epascarello I think so, I can show and hide it by using: $('nobr:contains("Tool or Material?")').closest('tr').show(); & $('nobr:contains("Tool or Material?")').closest('tr').hide();

Comment: Solved the problem, I removed the mandatory requirement for tool or material and it now works...not exactly ideal though, I'd like to have the element mandatory